# How to toggle show/hide Tawk Floating Chat Button in Angular 14+?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tawk.to

I have added the Tawk.to chat widget to my Angular 14+ project by placing the following script in the head tag of my index.html file:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {}, Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
            (function () {
                var s1 = document.createElement("script"), s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                s1.async = true;
                s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/*********/######';
                s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
                s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
                s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
            })();
            Tawk_API.customStyle = {
                visibility: {
                    desktop: {
                        position: 'br',
                        xOffset: '60px',
                        yOffset: 20
                    },
                    mobile: {
                        position: 'br',
                        xOffset: 20,
                        yOffset: 60
                    }
                }
            };
        </script>
        <!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

However, I would like to be able to toggle the visibility of the chat widget from within my Angular component. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

I have attempted to toggle the visibility of the Tawk.to chat widget using JavaScript in my Angular component. I expected the chat widget to hide when I clicked on a button, and to show when I clicked on the button again. However, the chat widget remained visible regardless of the button's state.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this tool but it seems to add `div.widget-visible` to the body.
If it is the case, I would hide it by CSS like this:

```css
body.hideTawkTo .widget-visible {display: none}
```

and then in Angular component just toggle the body class:

```js
document.body.classList.add('hideTawkTo');
```

```js
document.body.classList.remove('hideTawkTo');
```